# Замена функции активации в нейронной сети. Python

Tags: python, нейронные-сети

Есть код простенькой нейронной сети (кусок)

```
import numpy as np

def net_build():
    def linear(_in, _out):  # network linear layer
        w = np.random.randn(_in * _out).astype(np.float32) * .1
        b = np.random.randn(_out).astype(np.float32) * .1
        return (_in, _out), np.concatenate((w, b))

    s0, p0 = linear(4, 10)
    s1, p1 = linear(10, 10)
    s2, p2 = linear(10, 2)
    return [s0, s1, s2], np.concatenate((p0, p1, p2))

shapes, params = net_build()
```

Уже неделю пытаюсь поменять функцию активации с линейной, тут

```
s1, p1 = linear(10, 10)**
```

на Sigmoid / ReLu и ничего не выходит.

З.Ы. сам ни капли не программист, так что буду признателен любой помощи.

---

> Попробуйте написать функцию активации, которая возвращает сам элемент без изменений

Попробовал, вот что получилось и оно работает

```
import numpy as np

def net_build():
    def linear(_in, _out):  # network linear layer
        w = np.random.randn(_in * _out).astype(np.float32) * .1
        b = np.random.randn(_out).astype(np.float32) * .1
        return (_in, _out), np.concatenate((w, b))

    def sigmoid(_in, _out):  # network sigmoid layer
        def sgm(x):
            return x #1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))
        w = np.random.randn(_in * _out).astype(np.float32) * .1
        b = np.random.randn(sgm(_out)).astype(np.float32) * .1
        return (_in, _out), np.concatenate((w, b))

    s0, p0 = linear(4, 10)
    s1, p1 = sigmoid(10, 10)
    s2, p2 = linear(10, 2)
    return [s0, s1, s2], np.concatenate((p0, p1, p2))

shapes, params = net_build()
print(shapes, params)
```

> а потом заменить её на сигмоид короче

Заменил и теперь оно выдает ошибку:

```
import numpy as np

def net_build():
    def linear(_in, _out):  # network linear layer
        w = np.random.randn(_in * _out).astype(np.float32) * .1
        b = np.random.randn(_out).astype(np.float32) * .1
        return (_in, _out), np.concatenate((w, b))

    def sigmoid(_in, _out):  # network sigmoid layer
        def sgm(x):
            return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))
        w = np.random.randn(_in * _out).astype(np.float32) * .1
        b = np.random.randn(sgm(_out)).astype(np.float32) * .1
        return (_in, _out), np.concatenate((w, b))

    s0, p0 = linear(4, 10)
    s1, p1 = sigmoid(10, 10)
    s2, p2 = linear(10, 2)
    return [s0, s1, s2], np.concatenate((p0, p1, p2))

shapes, params = net_build()
print(shapes, params)
```

Сама ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/_NN/tests12_Sigm/data/b.py", line 22, in <module>
    shapes, params = net_build()
  File "E:/_NN/tests12_Sigm/data/b.py", line 18, in net_build
    s1, p1 = sigmoid(10, 10)
  File "E:/_NN/tests12_Sigm/data/b.py", line 13, in sigmoid
    b = np.random.randn(sgm(_out)).astype(np.float32) * .1
  File "mtrand.pyx", line 1232, in numpy.random.mtrand.RandomState.randn
  File "mtrand.pyx", line 1389, in numpy.random.mtrand.RandomState.standard_normal
  File "_common.pyx", line 577, in numpy.random._common.cont
TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Comment: еще один человек который место Hello World пишет нейросети и жалуется что ничего не понимает

Comment: Покажите ваши попытки, как вы меняли

Comment: Вы не совсем правы, @Данил. В нейросетях совершенно не разбираюсь и, видимо из-за возраста, уже и не разберусь никогда. Для меня это темный лес. Поэтому я пишу свои Hello world используя существующие сети и мне это нравится, что в этом плохого?

Comment: @dIm0n, в том то и дело, я не могу даже представить как это поменять. Ведь, навряд ли если я просто назову функцию сигмоидом она им станет. А как прикрутить функцию с одним параметром ` f(x) = 1 / (1 + e^(-x))`  на место линейной с двумя я не знаю, голова уже пухнет. Поэтому и зарегистритовался тут

Comment: @SatOrY а если попробовать линейную сделать с одним, а не сигмоид с двумя, а потом подставить вместо линейной сигмоид? Что такое у вас линейная функция активации мне непонятно просто, весь смысл функций активации это добавить нелинейность как раз, поэтому не могу дать конкретный ответ. Попробуйте написать функцию активации, которая возвращает сам элемент без изменений, а потом заменить её на сигмоид короче

Comment: @dIm0n, спасибо за советы, попробовал, ниже результат

Comment: @SatOrY https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.randn.html

Answer (score 0):

У вас это неправильно

```
 b = np.random.randn(sgm(_out)).astype(np.float32) * .1
```

Видимо нужно

```
 b = np.random.randn(_out).astype(np.float32) * .1
```

sgm дает float,а np.random.randn нужно int(целое).